# Can't see GridView with OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to put table from MS Access to `GridView` using `OleDbDataReader`. Visual Studio doesn't show any errors or warnings, but I still even can't see my `GridView`. Here is how I'm trying:

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=kpp-lab-3-4-db-1.mdb";
OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
Connection.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM `View`";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, Connection);
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
reader.Close();
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. `GridView` in code has parameter `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`. You have to set it to `True` and then it will works.